# "mysql command line client not found. Please fix its path in Preferences -> Administration" mysqlworkbench no me deja importar sakila-data.sql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Ese es el output que me sale, cuando quiero importar sakila-data.sql.
LINUX MINT utilizo como SO.
Gracias desde ya.

Comment: ¿has verificado que tienes el mysql bien instalado?   Lo que te dice el error es que no lo encuentra instalado en tu sistema básicamente, o bien el mysqlworkbench no sabe encontrarlo (ante lo cual podrias ejecutar un `which mysql` para localizarlo y agregarlo a las preferencias de ese programa)

Comment: @masterguru como hago para editarlo?  /usr/bin/mysql eso es lo que me da al ejecutar el comando which mysql, como hago para editar el path? 

Basicamente lo que pasa es que sakila no tiene los datos de la base de datos, esta vacia porque no me deja importar el sakila-data.sql.

Quiero aprender SQL jaja

Comment: Haz lo que te dice el error: "Please fix its path in Preferences -> Administration". O sea, vete a las **Preferencias**, y dentro de ellas busca la opción **Administración** y en algun lugar te debe estar pidiendo el path del **mysql** supongo (no uso el mysqlworkbench y no te puedo asegurar que sea eso al 100% pero es lo que dice el error aprox.), y en el path (o quizas es **ruta** si esta en español) le pones **/usr/bin/mysql**

Comment: @masterguru no puedo ir a preferencias y administracion porque estoy en linux, se que tengo que ponerle esa ruta, ahora como, no tengo idea, busque en sitios pero todo me parece en ingles

Comment: Da igual donde estes... las Preferencias (Preferences) las encontraras en el menu Edit (Editar), al final de todo, y alli encontrarás la opción "Administrator" (me lo acabo de instalar y comprobar en mi ubuntu)

Comment: masterguru si si, ahi pude jaja gracias